# LINQ: Get an object in array containing property with specific name and value

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

Trying to select an object in an array by using one of its properties with a specific value as a "pointer" so to speak. My aim is to do this with linq

Example:

```
    {
        "A": "ValA",
        "B": "ValB",
        "C": [
            {
                "D": "ValD1",
                "E": "ValE1",
                "F": "ValF1"
            },
            {
                "D": "ValD2",
                "E": "ValE2",
                "F": "ValF2"
            },
            {
                "D": "ValD2",
                "E": "ValE3",
                "F": "ValF3"
            }
         ]
    }
```

So what i want to do is to get the objects n Array "C" that contains property "D" with Value "ValD2". As there are two objects i want to have the LINQ query to result in returning a list with both objects. If there would be on one object containing property "D" with Value "ValD2". I Would only get back one object containing those parameters so to speak.

That is:

```
       [
            {
                "D": "ValD2",
                "E": "ValE2",
                "F": "ValF2"
            },
            {
                "D": "ValD2",
                "E": "ValE3",
                "F": "ValF3"
            }
       ]
```

So far I've managed to get all objects in array C by doing this:

```
json.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().Where(x => x.ContainsKey("C")).ToList()
```

Comment: Can you use a class wrapper around your JSON data and deserialize the results or do you have to manipulate plain JSON?

Comment: @Volodymyr Sadly i have to manipulate plain json. :(

Answer (score -1):

So i guess i found it with the help of Both Abdus Salam Azad and Prasad Telkikar:

```
json.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().Where(x => x.ContainsKey("D")).Where(x => x.Property("D").Value.ToString() == "ValD2").ToList()
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Just a minor remark: you could probably chain your `Where(...)` calls into one: `json.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().Where(x => x.ContainsKey("C") && x.Property("D")?.Value?.ToString() == "ValD2").ToList()`. Note, that property `x.Property("D")` can be `null` if `D` does not exist, so it would be worth it to check this too (e.g., with `?.` operator)

Comment: Of course you are totally right @Volodymyr . Thank you. :)